# NodeJS: Cannot use import statement outside a module(already tried type :"module")

Tags: node.js, import

I have received a NodeJS application from client and trying to get it up and running. The very first issue I received is "Cannot use import statement outside a module". So, I tried including "type": "module" in package.json but it still is not working. Upon providing "nodemon src\server.js" command after including the above line, I get Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\MyApp\APIs\src\app' imported from D:\Projects\MyApp\APIs\src\server.js

When I change

```
import app from './app';
```

with

```
import app from './app.js';
```

the error goes but it occurs for other imports. For example:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\MyApp\APIs\src\routes\user' imported from D:\Projects\MyApp\APIs\src\app.js

So again, if I change

```
import UserRoutes from './routes/v1/user/user';
```

with

```
import UserRoutes from './routes/v1/user/user.js';
```

the error vanishes for this import but again pops up for other import statement. There are many js files and they have been imported like this only. Do I need to include extension for all of them wherever they are imported or is there a way around to fix it?
Node version I am using is 14.17.0

Comment: Does the answer make the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve by using the node module structure :

Full Command :

```
node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node app.js
```

For more details check [this](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).